# On merge, choose non-null value of same column from either dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have three dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'code': [123, 124], 'name': ['Manchester', 'Liverpool']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'code': [123], 'group': ['b'], 'items_highcost': [10]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'code': [123, 124], 'group': ['b', 'c'], 'items_not_highcost': [11, 8]})
```

I want to merge them into a single frame, but excluding any rows that aren't in `df1`, so I do two left joins:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='code', how='left')
df_merged = pd.merge(df_merged, df3, on='code', how='left')
```

This gives me the following merged dataset:

```
   code        name group_x  items_highcost group_y  items_not_highcost
0   123  Manchester       b              10       b                  11
1   124   Liverpool     NaN             NaN       c                   8
```

But I want there to be a single `group` column for each row, with the non-null value of `group` in it, whether from `df2` or `df3` or both. (It's safe to assume that the value of `group` will be the same the same codes in `df2` and `df3`, as they're coming from the same data source.)

Right now I'm doing this:

```
def get_group(row):
    if row['group_x']: return row['group_x']
    if row['group_y']: return row['group_y']
    return None
df_merged['group'] = df_merged.apply(get_group, axis=1)
df_merged.drop(['group_x', 'group_y'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

This works, but is ugly. Ideally I would't have the intermediate step with `group_x` and `group_y`, but could get the non-null value in a single step. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you're doing is filling the missing values in which case you could instead call `combine_first` successively:

```
In [196]:
df1.combine_first(df2).combine_first(df3)

Out[196]:
   code group  items_highcost  items_not_highcost        name
0   123     b            10.0                11.0  Manchester
1   124     c             NaN                 8.0   Liverpool
```

Comment: Thanks - do you mean do this instead of `merge`?

Comment: In your case this will be simpler and it's more what you're trying to do as you're filling missing values